# Is there a way to use a service outside of its controller without injecting it as a dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

For example, there's `XController` and there's `XService`, but there's also the `YService` and I want to use it in several controllers without having to inject into the controller as a dependency in the following way:

```
private readonly IYService _yService;

XController(IYService yService)
{
    _YService = YService;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it? I want to use this service in several controllers since I'm logging the controllers and storing what has changed, the old value, the new value, and the date time. These are all stored into a database.

Comment: There are many ways for classes to acquire dependencies, but Constructor Injection (CI) is *by far* the most effective technique for accomplishing this. If you feel that CI is unsuited for your particular case, please describe in detail what your specific case is and why you feel that CI is unsuited. Based on that understanding we can provide alternatives, or comment on your design. Either way, as it currently stands, your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Is `YService` a _replacement_ for `XService`? Or an additional service that the controller _can_ use but doesn't _need_ to. You can also do dependency injection through properties, which is sometimes better for optional dependencies.

Comment: @DStanley it's not. YService is a standalone service and its purpose would to store logs of the controller into the database.

Comment: Then I would make it a _property_ of the controller and either use dependency injection to set it automatically or set it explicitly when you create the controller.

Comment: If your "XController" ~depends on~ IYService to execute.....that is what Dependency Injection is.    Perhaps you want to audit these type of changes at the DbContext level instead? https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/audit-trail-implementation-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 0):

Can use one of these

1. Setter/Property Injection

   ```
     [Dependency]    
     public IYService _yService { get; set; }
   ```
2. Method Injection

   ```
    [InjectionMethod]    
    public void Method(IYService _yService)    
    {    
       // your logic    
    }
   ```

[Please click here for more details](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/what-is-dependency-injection-and-what-are-its-types2)